# Getting error while running the react native app in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

This is the error:

```
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-NativeModulesApple' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-runtimescheduler' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-debug' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-utils' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'KtGuru' from project 'KtGuru')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'KtGuru' from project 'KtGuru')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'KtGuru' from project 'KtGuru')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'fmt' from project 'Pods')

2023-08-04 17:07:17.905 xcodebuild[31763:268428] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/mokshassd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KtGuru-gopqqodazgxbgvgbbcsqhqioupxf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E0001FA30.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I have tried this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Also deleting the pods folder and also clearing the cache but getting the same error

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: have anyone found a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script and than build

> cd ios && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install